# Displaying a parameter's description value

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

In Crystal Reports v 11, is it possible to display the 'Parameter Description' value on the report, as opposed to only the parameter value?  Whenever I drag the parameter onto the report to display it, only the value is displayed, and I want to print the description.

Note:  I'm working in Crystal 11 (XI), not the .NET Crystal Report plug-in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Ryan--there isn't a native mechanism to grab these values.  A user-function library (UFL) might be an approach worth investigating.

In lieu of that, I handle this a number of ways:

1. a formula with a case statement to convert the value to a description.
2. a custom function that does the same a #1; custom functions can be shared w/ other reports via the BOE repository
3. use a subreport to query a table that can covert the value to a description.  store the values in an array in the Detail section (suppressed), then Join() the array in the report footer.  if you embed the subreport in its own section, it will expand as needed to accommodate an expansive list
4. you might be able to adapt #3 to use a list of values exposed by BO's query as a web service (QAAWS), but I haven't experimented with this.  If it doesn't have an associated schema document, CR won't be able to use the XML webservice as a data source.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the #3 idea.  The parameter is dynamic, so what I was able to do was take the parameter value and pass it to a "mini" subreport that simply queried the database for the description field off of the parameter value.  Luckily the parameter value is unique.

Answer (score 2):

**First,** Concatenate the parameter value and the description together and delimit the two values using a pipe '|' or other lesser used character

Example:
CustomerID, CustomerName -> 12345|ABC Company

**Second** Use a **Crystal function** with an array to display the description side on your report i.e everything after your delimiting character

```
Numbervar i;
Numbervar j;
StringVar Array z := "";

Local StringVar Array x := split(Join({?My Parameter},";"),";");

j := count(x);

redim preserve z[j];

for i := 1 to j do(
z[i] := right(x[i],Length(x[i])-instr(x[i],"|")) 
);

join(z,",")
```

**Third.** Create a second function like the one above to return the Parameter value to the left of the delimiter to use as part of the report's Selection Formula**

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to directly get at the description (several other posts scattered around the interwebs seem to agree). If you have a small(-ish) number of parameter options, you can just create a formula or function that contains a case-statement that will translate the value to its description.

Answer (score 0):

I got over the shock that Crystal Reports somehow is able to retrieve the description of a parameter but it doesn't expose it to be used in formulas. Being forced to duplicate the definition of parameters and description seems to me bad form, simply because one is not supposed to duplicate things when programming. An alternative hack (besides all the ones listed) would be to make your Values and Descriptions as values of a SQL data source (hardcode them in SQL). Then you can populate your parameter from said data source and you will have the Descriptions available as a field. That way you only have "one version of the truth" that maps your values to your descriptions, although more moving pieces.

Answer (score 0):

See: 1678487 - How to display parameter descriptions instead of parameter values in the Crystal Reports at: https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/1678487

Answer (score -1):

There is a new function that can actually be used for displaying the descriptions of a parameter on a report.

Source : https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2037542

I will paste the entire document for those users who don't have to access to this page.

A new function GetValueDescriptions() is added in Crystal Reports 2016, to allow user create formula that could operate / display descriptions of selected value for a parameter.

GetValueDescriptions() supports all kinds of parameters (single and multiple, discrete and range). Below is an formula example where {?customerMultiDiscreteAndRange} is a multiple range parameter:

﻿local stringVar range array im := GetValueDescriptions ({?customerMultiDiscreteAndRange});
local numberVar i := 1;
local stringVar out := "";

while i <= count(im) do
(
if (IncludesLowerBound ({?customerMultiDiscreteAndRange}[i])) then
( out := out + "["; )
else
( out := out + "("; );

if (HasLowerBound ({?customerMultiDiscreteAndRange}[i])) then
( out := out + GetLowerBound(im[i]) );

out := out + "..";

if (HasUpperBound ({?customerMultiDiscreteAndRange}[i])) then
( out := out + GetUpperBound(im[i]) );

if (IncludesUpperBound ({?customerMultiDiscreteAndRange}[i])) then
( out := out + "]"; )
else
( out := out + ")"; );

if (i < count(im)) then
out := out + ", ";

i:= i + 1;
);

out;﻿

Also note two new functions - GetLowerBound() and GetUpperBound(), they can be used to get correct lower / upper bound descriptions. These two are especially useful if Maximum() and Minimum() returns swapped descriptions.

Above formula example can be adjusted easily, e.g. to show both the value and descrition, or to satisfy more reporting needs.

To use these functions, upgrade your Crystal Reports to a release where the enhancement has been made.

See the SP Patch Level section for details and available patches.

For SAP Crystal Reports, version for Eclipse:

These functions are supported for runtime only since SP22, with following limitations:

Static multi-range parameters are not supported in SAP Crystal Reports, version for Eclipse runtime, which is the same as before. Dynamic multi-range parameters are supported.
"Value Options" to show description is not supported in the embedded designer in SAP Crystal Reports, version for Eclipse. If you have an existing report designed in SAP Crystal Reports 2016 with parameters' "Value Options" to show description, any modification resaved in the embedded designer will overwrite the "Value Options" to show value. Instead, reports created in SAP Crystal Reports 2016 with the "Value Options" to show description is supported in SAP Crystal Reports, version for Eclipse runtime.
To download the latest Support Packages of SAP Crystal Reports, version for Eclipse:

https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/SAP+Crystal+Reports+version+for+Eclipse+-+Downloads